# in python - how to save multi HTML Source code to one single text file

Tags: python

I have list for Links (stored in links.txt file )

This code can save result of one link
but I do not know how to make it download **ALL** the source codes of **ALL** links inside (links.txt) and SAVE THEM AS **ONE SINGLE text file** for next step of processing ...

```
import urllib.request    
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=abc&_sacat=0&_pgn=1", "result.txt")
```

Example links form links.txt

```
https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=abc&_sacat=0&_pgn=1
https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=abc&_sacat=0&_pgn=2
https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=abc&_sacat=0&_pgn=3
https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=abc&_sacat=0&_pgn=4
https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=abc&_sacat=0&_pgn=5
https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=abc&_sacat=0&_pgn=6
https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=abc&_sacat=0&_pgn=7
....
```

Comment: assuming you arent trying to save as *.html, you can use a dict and serialize it using json module

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply dear @DelphiX , sadly I do not have much knowledge in python

Comment: Did you try writing a `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's usual better to use `requests` lib, so you should start from installing it:

```
pip install requests
```

Then I'd propose to read the `links.txt` line by line, download all the data you need and store it in file `output.txt`:

```py
import requests

data = []
# collect all the data from all links in the file 
with open('links.txt', 'r') as links:
    for link in links:
        response = requests.get(link)
        data.append(response.text)

# put all collected to a single file
with open('output.txt', 'w+') as output:
    for chunk in data:
        print(chunk, file=output)
```

Comment: sadly give error   `, line 8, in <module>
    data.appent(response.text)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'appent'`

Comment: `data.append(response.text)`

Comment: @user13602012 I fix the typo

Answer (score 4):

## urllib

```py
import urllib.request

with open('links.txt', 'r') as f:
    links = f.readlines()

for link in links:
    with urllib.request.urlopen(link) as f:
        # get html text
        html = f.read().decode('utf-8')

        # append html to file
        with open('result.txt', 'w+') as f:
            f.write(html)
```

## [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)

you could also use requests library which i find much more readable

```py
pip install requests
```

```py
import requests

with open('links.txt', 'r') as f:
    links = f.readlines()

for link in links:
    response = requests.get(link)
    html = response.text

    # append html to file
    with open('result.txt', 'w+') as f:
        f.write(html)
```

#### Use loop for page navigation

Use for loop to generate page links as the only thing that is changing is the page no.

```py
links = [
  f'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=abc&_sacat=0&_pgn={n}'
  for n in range(1, 10) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
]
```

or as you go along

```
for n in range(1, 10):
  link = f'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=abc&_sacat=0&_pgn={n}'

  [...]
```

Comment: looking good and import urllib.request work whiteout error , but still it give result of 1 single link instead all links inside (links.txt)

Comment: `import requests` give error ,, maybe it is safier to use  `urllib.request`    //// error with import requests is 
`line 8, in <module>
    f.write(html)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`

Comment: requests is a module, you have to install it using pip

Comment: requests is good such that we wont have to worry about formatting from utf-8 to ascii, as the module does it for you

Comment: yes `requests` module already installed , `Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\a-data\appdata\loc
al\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2020.4.5.1)`

Comment: use `response.text` as opposed to `response.content`